# Eigen Assertion Error when Converting from MatrixXf to ArrayXf

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I wrote a simple program that adds a scalar to a Random matrix.

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main() {
    Eigen::MatrixXf mat = Eigen::MatrixXf::Random(100, 100);
    Eigen::ArrayXf arr = mat.array() + 1;
}
```

The program compiles without any errors. However, when executing this line:

```
Eigen::ArrayXf arr = mat.array() + 1;
```

I get the following error:

```
Assertion failed: (other.rows() == 1 || other.cols() == 1), function resizeLike, file /usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.3.7/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h, line 374.
```

I read the official documentation (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html) and I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Apparently, I had to store the result of the addition in a MatrixXf, not in an ArrayXf.

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main() {
    Eigen::MatrixXf mat = Eigen::MatrixXf::Random(100, 100);
    Eigen::MatrixXf arr = mat.array() + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I did anything with Eigen, but I believe you can't mix Arrays and Matrices like that.

However, it seems like you're generating a 100x100 matrix with random numbers, and I'm not sure why it trips up. I don't have Eigen readily available at the moment, but changing it to use fixed size arrays seems to be working on Godbolt.

```cpp
// Type your code here, or load an example.
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main() 
{
    Eigen::Matrix<float, 100, 100> mat = Eigen::Matrix<float, 100, 100>::Random();
    Eigen::Array<float, 100, 100> arr = mat.array() + 1;

    std::cout << "Mat 0,0: " << mat(0,0) << "\nArr 0,0: " << arr(0,0) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Mat 2,0: " << mat(2,0) << "\nArr 2,0: " << arr(2,0);

    return 0;
}
```

```
ASM generation compiler returned: 0

Execution build compiler returned: 0

Program returned: 0

Mat 0,0: 0.680375
Arr 0,0: 1.68038
Mat 2,0: 0.566198
Arr 2,0: 1.5662
```

https://godbolt.org/z/9xu5oW

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, that does not solve my problem. The code I posted was just a simple example. What I need to do is multiply two dynamic matrices (matrix multiplication) and then add the result element-wise to another dynamic matrix (C = Ax + B). Do you know how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding `Array` object to `MatrixXf` (aka, `Matrix<float, Dynamic, Dynamic>`) would be `ArrayXXf` (aka, `Array<float, Dynamic, Dynamic>`). `ArrayXf` is a typedef for `Array<float, Dynamic, 1>`, similar to a `VectorXf` (aka, `Matrix<float, Dynamic, 1>`).

The following should work as expected:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>

int main() {
    Eigen::MatrixXf mat = Eigen::MatrixXf::Random(100, 100);
    Eigen::ArrayXXf arr = mat.array() + 1;
}
```